# Can clang-format only sort-includes and leave the rest of the file unchanged?

Tags: clang-format

I have a C++ project that is currently not clang-formatted at all. I trying to incrementally migrate the project to clang-format and I'm trying to start with a small change.

Is there a way to `clang-format --sort-includes` without applying any other formatting changes?

I've tried `clang-format --sort-includes --style=none` and this just doesn't do anything at all.

I've also tried using a empty clang-format file but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Forgot to note, I just built clang-format from the latest commit. `clang-format version 17.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 97f3bb73a29a566e99e33ae4338c2c3d9957e561)`

Answer (score 1):

Not really, however if your main intention is just to sort the include list in the source files, then the more appropriate tool is to use [iwyu](https://include-what-you-use.org/), as it is aware of the symbols required instead of just blind sorting by clang-format.
It will explicitly include header files in alphabetical order which can also prevent a lot of out-of-order transitive include issues.